# String too large for BigInteger initialization in Java?

Tags: java, string, biginteger

I'm using a string with 80,000,000 characters(1's and 0's) to initialize a BigInteger in Java. It seems to take an extremely long time to initialize(so long in fact that I let it run for an hour before giving up. I've made sure that it is stuck on initialization and I am wondering if a string that large is Too large? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks guys.

Comment: It's a large integer. What did you expect would happen? More to the point, we need to know something about your specs to determine even in principle if it could handle such an operation.

Comment: Are you parsing the `String` in base 2 (or base 10)? Actually, can you post some of the code? (Also, 80 million characters is a very large `String`).

Comment: BigInteger file = new BigInteger(stringFile,2);

Comment: Can you post some code please (in the post, not the comments).  A string can only be 2,147,483,647 characters long, so you are fine with 80,000,000.

Comment: I think the only way to know if 80 million characters is too large is to attempt to let it run to completion.  If it doesn't throw any errors, it wasn't too large.

Comment: Have you tried running the profiler?

Comment: There's no ctor for BigInteger that takes a File, so you mean you just have a String, right?

Comment: I have not tried a profiler. hmm. I did a quick search and it looks like a cool tool. Is there a profiler built into eclipse?

Comment: @markspace yeah sorry thats a String.

Comment: stuck here `java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
 at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:473)
 at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:597)`

Comment: If you do need my specs, the ones that make a difference

Comment: CPU = i5 2500k OC @ 4.4GHZ, 16GB ram

Comment: I recommend trying a series of smaller values and timing them. Based on my timings (1.3 seconds for 1,000,000, 5.6 for 2,000,000, 142 for 10,000,000) it's clear that the parse time is not `O(n)`.

Comment: I see. Good plan. Thanks.

Comment: Im trying 20,000,000 and it is taking a significant amount of time... I wonder if adding 1,000,000 at a time would be faster... lets see!!!

Comment: Yeah, it's always best to explore runtimes starting with small magnitudes and working up: I started with 1,000 and 10,000 digits before trying 1,000,000.

Comment: If this is a real problem, and not simply "let's see if this works," then I recommend using the `BigDecimal(byte[])` constructor, and parsing the binary string yourself. I looked at the `BigDecimal` constructor, and it uses a general-but-inefficient approach that involves repeated multiplies and adds.